# How to wait for page to re-open

Tags: selenium-webdriver, serenity-bdd

I have a page where extra features become available if you login. Login is via a popup panel. On successful login, the page is reloaded (so that options appropriate to user rights are dynamically added to the interface).

```
    @Override
 @Step("Logs in as: {0}")
    public <T extends Actor> void performAs(T actor) {
        actor.attemptsTo(         
            Open.browserOn(homePage),
            Click.on(homePage.loginMenuItem),
            Enter.theValue(authenticated(actor).username())
                 .into(homePage.userField),
            Enter.theValue(authenticated(actor).password())
                 .into(homePage.pwdField),
            Click.on(homePage.loginBtn),            
        );
  }
```

The test uses a question to query state of the page. However, what I am seeing is that test seems to be operating on the page before it is reloaded. (times out waiting for target, returns old values elements on the page depending on how I do the question). I can see the revised page being displayed. Clearly, I need to wait till page is reopened in response to click before I ask the question which I thought selenium was supposed to do. But how do I do I wait? If I add:

```
            Open.browserOn(homePage)
```

after click, then it works - mostly. Sometimes it still seems to respond to old page. But if I rerun, it usually works. Ie the above method is flaky. I could just wait 2 seconds, but theoretically it could still fail if authentication server was being slow. Ideas please.

Answer (score 1):

On the line before

```
Click.on(homePage.loginBtn)
```

grab an element, like the login button and store it in a variable. Then click on the login button ... then wait for the login button to become stale. A stale element indicates that the page has refreshed. After that point, you are ready to access the page again.

I don't know what all helper functions you have available but it should look something like this

```
WebElement loginButton = driver.findElement(homePage.loginBtn);
Click.on(homePage.loginBtn)
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(loginButton));
// do stuff
```

Comment: oddly, it hits error, saying element not visible. Tried with different element (since login button would disappear before page loaded.However, I worked further on this and used the WaitUntil.wait to search for element that only on form after user has logged in. This works.